# Azure SQL: null fields on get()

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a table `Friends` that I use to store relations between my `Users`.

I can send data to the table with no problem, all the fields have the desired value. But when I try to get the data from de DB, all the fields but Id are null.

Any idea ? Thanks !

**The code:**

```
Static.mClient.getTable(Friends.class).insert(f1).get();
Static.mClient.getTable(Friends.class).insert(f2).get();

System.out.println("Added friends !");
System.out.println(f1.Id + ": " + f1.User1 + " <-> " + f1.User2);
System.out.println(f2.Id + ": " + f2.User1 + " <-> " + f2.User2);

System.out.println("Now getting data...")
List<Friends> l = Static.mClient.getTable(Friends.class).execute().get();
for (Friends friends : l) {
    System.out.println(friends.Id + ": " + friends.User1 + " <-> " + friends.User2);
}
```

**The output:**

```
06-14 16:44:41.916 8504-8557/com.travel2gather I/System.out: Added friends !
06-14 16:44:41.916 8504-8557/com.travel2gather I/System.out: 8744e40ba601402cae229c0ebd2a3e7d: ec99e0f1d61447deb246477f551dddb2 <-> 1c7fcc47a03c4063a0e4f8fcd4a0fb97
06-14 16:44:41.916 8504-8557/com.travel2gather I/System.out: 7da1c6905d7e495bbd1fecfa33b4a8f3: ec99e0f1d61447deb246477f551dddb2 <-> 751631d38737493aadef399474bb0a13
06-14 16:44:41.916 8504-8557/com.travel2gather I/System.out: Now getting data...
06-14 16:47:30.322 10840-10889/com.travel2gather I/System.out: 7da1c6905d7e495bbd1fecfa33b4a8f3: null <-> null
06-14 16:47:30.322 10840-10889/com.travel2gather I/System.out: 8744e40ba601402cae229c0ebd2a3e7d: null <-> null
```

But when I check the DB, I can see that the fields `User1` and `User2` are not null and have the values they are supposed to have...

Answer (score 1):

This may caused by losing 'get' methods for User1 and User2 in your Friends class. Add 'get' and 'set' methods for all properties then try again.

Comment: I have all my getters/setters on the class `Friends` (Both front-end/back-end). I can retrieve the ID, but the fields are null, any other idea ?